# Script for wrapping LaTeX environments around texts from files

Tags: shell-script, sed, latex

To wrap filecontents (Latex Source) between two tags.
This has to be nested as shown.

to add

```
\begin{question}
question.tex #This is Latex file with Question Source
\begin{solution}
Solution.tex  #This is latex source file for solution
\end{solution}
\end{question}
```

My question seems to be not clear.  A little more as needed

Out.txt should contain

```
\begin{question}
Contents of Question.tex File
\begin{solution}
Contents of Solution.tex file
\end{solution}
\end{question}
```

Contents of question.tex is a text with latex commands etc.  Similarly this is same with solution.tex

Comment: How do you tell the end of a question in your input?

Comment: Question text is some latex code from a file question.tex.  Similarly solution text is latex code from another file.   I have changed the question accordingly.   Thanks for replying

Comment: And what *exactly* do you want the script to do? Defining the problem is often 90% of solving it. We can't do the former for you.

Comment: @steeldriver Please go through my new edit.

Comment: `{ printf %s\\n '\begin{question}'; cat Question.tex; printf %s\\n '\begin{solution}'; cat Solution.tex; printf %s\\n '\end{solution}' '\end{question}'; } > Out.txt`

Comment: Thanks this is working.  I did not know about printf %s which did the trick my content had control characters for latex environments.  Thanks for the reply. I would have upvoted had it been given as an answer.

Comment: Why not use \include or similar? TeX can read other files.

Comment: I'm with @Gilles.  TeX has file inclusion, so this whole approach is poor.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,  I have a collection of Problems and Solutions as snippets which are source for three frameworks  1. Latex for producing pdf 2. Moodle for Virtual Course 3 Quiz platform under Drupal.   Basically requirement is about handling numerous small files.  So script for clubbing them and pushing these three outputs is the necessity.  Thanks for showing interest in this question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As don_crissti [answered in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307424/script-for-wrapping-latex-environments-around-texts-from-files#comment540473_307424), I'll include it here to close the question out:

```
{ printf %s\\n '\begin{question}'; 
  cat Question.tex; 
  printf %s\\n '\begin{solution}'; 
  cat Solution.tex; 
  printf %s\\n '\end{solution}' '\end{question}';
} > Out.txt
```

The braces open up a sequence of commands, all of whose output will get redirected into the Out.txt file. The printf statements simply print the associated text strings while the `cat` commands include the files Question.tex and Solution.tex.